# How to use Jenkins JobDSL to set 'polling ignore commits from certain users' in Git Plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, dsl

I have the following:

```
job {

  scm {

     git {

        remote {
        url(GIT_URL) 
        }
        branch('master')  
     }
 }
}
```

It works pretty well but I would like for it to set ' polling ignore commits from certain users'. How is that done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
    job {
      scm {
         git {
            remote {
            url(GIT_URL) 
            }
            branch('master')
            extensions {
              userExclusion {
                excludedUsers('user')
              }
            }
         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add explanation why this is working and why the one in question doesn't?